# VK API мгновенное получение записей со стены сообщества

Tags: vkontakte-api

Необходимо **сразу** при создании записи на стене сообщества (**не моего**) произвести какое действие (*не суть, пока что просто вывести сообщение на стандартный вывод*).

Проблемы:
Как можно ловить события в группе, не выполняя запрос каждую секунду?
Как это можно сделать зная только логин-пароль?

Comment: «Как можно ловить события в группе» https://vk.com/dev/callback_api но для этого нужен свой веб-сервер

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя, придётся делать запросы каждую секунду. Даже на сайте, если вы посмотрите запросы/ответы к серверу в "спокойном" состоянии, то увидите, что сайт шлёт ajax-запросы к своим серверам для проверки обновлений.

Comment: Обманывать не надо, у ВК есть Callback API специально для ловли событий в группе, который работает без всяких там ajax

Comment: Действительно есть. Но этот способ работает только если вы администратор сообщества. С чужими сообществами не сработает

Answer (score 0):

Есть https://vk.com/dev/bots_longpoll
Но нужно буть руководителем в этом сообществе